# Is there a VS Code shortcut to move focus from input box in interactive pane to code input/output cell?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know that CRTL+1, CRTL+2, etc. moves the focus between panes. For example, I can use CRTL+2 to move the focus from the file I'm editing to the python interactive pane input box where it's labeled "Type code here and press Shift+Enter to run".

What I'm looking to do, though, is to move the focus from that box to the input/output cells in the interactive window.

I know I can use CRTL+M to toggle tab to move the focus but that can be a lot of toggling.

I also see that there is there this github issue but I don't think it's addressing my question.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97992

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of interest to you might be these new commands:

> Move focus to the interactive window
>
> There are two new commands for placing focus in the interactive
> window.
>
> `interactive.input.focus` - Move focus to the input editor in the
> interactive window. `interactive.history.focus` - Move focus to
> history in interactive window.

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_66.md#move-focus-to-the-interactive-window

Comment: Really weird that this doesn't already have a shortcut mapped, right? I think it must be the most important shortcut in the whole IDE